# Awk Printing results in wrong fashion when running the results from stdout

Tags: shell, sh

I have an input and expecting the output which is shown below in shell script.

## Code

[image]

## Expected Output Result : Based on the expected output i want to filter which is having 2 and 4 results. So finally only two records has to be there.

START,2
START,4

## Current Output : Wrong

[image]

Comment: Please post code, sample input, output, etc. as text in your question, not as images.

Comment: For i in `seq 0 4`; do echo "START" echo $i | awk '{ ORS = (NR%2 ? "," :RS) }1' done

Comment: I want output based on above code is START,0   START, 1.... And so on

Comment: *in your question*

Comment: Could u pls let meknow what i am doing wrong

Comment: https://rextester.com/IYBQ86164

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to achieve the result you want, you have to change where is the "START" is echoed

```
for i in `seq 0 4`; do
echo "START,"$i | awk '{ ORS = (NR%2 ? "," : RS) }1'
done
```

**Output**
START,0,START,1,START,2,START,3,START,4

I wish that fixes your problem.

Comment: you should use both echos in the same line, because the echo generates normally a new line, so the first echo "START" will generate a new line after it (before it even reads the awk)